# Trying to make app secure with API key, but it isn't being used

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a web application that displays data from my cloud firestore. I'm about to release it to the public, but I don't want just anyone to be able to read/write to my database. 
I have currently restricted my API key to only allow requests from my website's url, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've even deleted it from the app entirely and it is still able to access the database.

Is there a rule I need to set up in my firestore to make it require an API key? I've googled plenty of things, but all I can find are articles on why it's ok to have your key be available to the public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to restrict access to Firestore based on some plaintext API key or web site domain.  If you're publishing an app that provides direct access to Cloud Firestore (or Cloud Storage, or Realtime Database), the only way to secure it is with a combination of [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).  The security rules allow you to express who can read and write which collections and document.

If you aren't using Firebase Authentication, and your default security rules allow universal read/write access, then anyone with an internet connection will be able to read and write every document.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on [Doug's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58381085) is to allow all users to write to specific documents that pre-exist and that have impossible to guess names. These document names then essentially become your own API keys, that you share (out of band) with the users of your app.

The security rules for this can be as simple as:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow create: if false;
      allow update: if exists(resource['__name__']);
      allow get: if true;
      allow list: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

So: anyone can get/update any existing document that they know the name of, but they can't create a document, nor get a list of all documents.

This prevents the need for using Firebase Authentication. On the other hand it means you can't lock down access on a per user basis. Any user that somehow gets access to the document name, can now read/write it at will.